# Google Play Music causing excessive wakeups

Tags: google-chrome, macos

I noticed lately that while listening to music via Google Play Music it would have moments of silence and eventually a popup will occur that says the page is not responding.

I checked the OSX Console, and see

```
process Google Chrome He[62823] caught causing excessive wakeups. Observed wakeups rate (per sec): 164; Maximum permitted wakeups rate (per sec): 150; Observation period: 300 seconds; Task lifetime number of wakeups: 66076
```

The Chrome app version is Version 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit).

How can I get back to a normal Google Play listening experience? (went back to my standby for now, VLC, for online streaming)

Comment: Did you try another browser? What happens?

Comment: So far so good on firefox.  After starting firefox, it immediately informed me I needed to update Adobe Flash player, which is interesting, since I thought Chrome came with it, so would've thought I'd have the latest.

Comment: Flash is a plugin. On my Windows 10 it was updated someday of the last week. Check the Flash plugin version on by writing on the Chrome address bar `chrome://plugins/`

Comment: By the way, as it looks to be a plugin issue, the question is off-topic for this site. I will vote to migrate it to [su].

Comment: dang, thought I was on topic. Noticed something else, I now hear ads, so my ad blocker on chrome may have been attributing to the issue.

Comment: No, this is fine here, I think. It's directly related to a web application.